# Regular expression for a string that does not start with a sequence

Tags: regex

I'm processing a bunch of tables using [this program](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/), but I need to ignore ones that start with the label "tbd_".

So far I have something like `[^tbd_]`, but that simply not match those characters.

Comment: How does SchemaSpy work?  Are you passing it a list of table names or are you passing it a regex and it's doing the matching?

Comment: I'm passing a regex (it's the -i flag) and it'll import the matches, or so it says in any case =)

Comment: @echoblaze: If you’re processing XML, why don’t you use an XML parser? That would be much easier than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 466, accepted):

You could use a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion:

```
^(?!tbd_).+
```

Or a negative look-behind assertion:

```
(^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!tbd_).*)
```

Or just plain old character sets and alternations:

```
^([^t]|t($|[^b]|b($|[^d]|d($|[^_])))).*
```

Comment: Is this restricted to any particular regex engines?

Comment: I only ask because that second one still seems to match tbd_ in my test.  The first one is great though.

Comment: Take a look at regular-expressions.info’s flavor comparison: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: @Gumbo - should that not end .* instead of .+?  A string that is tbd_ also starts with that... therefore by definition doesn't need to be followed by any other characters?  Otherwise, good example.  It *does* require a regex engine that supports lookaround though.

Comment: @balabaster: I don’t think he’s looking for empty strings. But if so, he can easily change that by replacing the `.+` by `.*`

Comment: Not looking for empty strings, thanks for the help! For some reason it's not working with my regex checker:
http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/toc.html
but I'll finish the xml script and see how that goes

Comment: A little typo: the second one is a negative look-behind assertion.

Comment: I am having issues with the first example using egrep, python's re, as well as a few online regex parsers (i.e. [Gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)).  It looks like these don't like a look-ahead with nothing preceeding.  Anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: Actually, after playing around a little more it looks like egrep is the only one that really doesn't like example #1.  I am able to make this work with python's re or Gskinner as long as the look-ahead is not the ONLY matchable string thing in the pattern (i.e. this does not work: '^(!?somestring)', but this does: '^(?!somestring).+').

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 2015 Find in Files. This expression uses both a negative look-ahead and a negative look-behind to find all C++ identifiers that start with "do_", but do not start with "do_Mode" and do not end with "Desc" or "Msg": "do_(?!Mode)(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*(?<!Desc|Msg))\b"

Comment: "Use a negative look-ahead assertion", I am sure I've been on the receiving end of a few of those.

Comment: Becareful with look ahead/behind its not supported by all browsers! This bite me in the butt

Comment: Thank you! The top one was the solution to my issue. I was looking for all lines that don't start with "clamp" in a Notepad++ regex `^(?!clamp).*$` saved the day.

Comment: The first one works great in most regex engine, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/72f9772e9b41).