# Check whether a string matches a regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to use JavaScript (I can also use jQuery) to do check whether a string matches the regex `^([a-z0-9]{5,})$`, and get a `true` or `false` result.

`match()` seems to check whether part of a string matches a regex, not the whole thing. Does it solve the problem? Can I adapt it to solve the problem? How?

Comment: Do you want a complete match, or just whether the string _contains_ a matching substring?

Comment: A complete match - not a matching substring.

Comment: I'm confused by how the problem was originally posed. Sure, `match` doesn't require the entire string to match the regex. But the `^` and `$` anchors ensure that **this regex** can **only possibly** match against the entire string - that's their **purpose**.

Comment: Anyway, relevant documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1787, accepted):

Use [`regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if all you want is a boolean result:

```js
console.log(/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test('abc1')); // false

console.log(/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test('abc12')); // true

console.log(/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test('abc123')); // true
```

...and you could remove the `()` from your regexp since you've no need for a capture.

Comment: What does the initial ^ in the regex does there?

Comment: @PedroD ^ implies begining or starts with

Comment: So how would you do the opposite? "doesn't start with..."

Comment: @PedroD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to do something with the groups? It gives an error if there is no match. In addition, it would be inefficient to first run test, then run match later.

Comment: @MikeSmith ...then run match, and check whether there are matches?

Answer (score 263):

Use `test()` method :

```
var term = "sample1";
var re = new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]{5,})$");
if (re.test(term)) {
    console.log("Valid");
} else {
    console.log("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Note that the version with `RegExp` allows to inject variable values into the regex string.

Comment: had to remove double quotes in `new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]{5,})$")` in order to make it work

Answer (score 146):

You can use `match()` as well:

```
if (str.match(/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/)) {
    alert("match!");
}
```

But `test()` seems to be faster as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/1895428).

**Important difference between `match()` and `test()`:**

`match()` works only with strings, but `test()` works also with integers.

```
12345.match(/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/); // ERROR
/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test(12345);  // true
/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test(null);   // false

// Better watch out for undefined values
/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test(undefined); // true
```

Comment: The reason it works with a number is because the number is coerced into a string, because it's given as a parameter when it's expecting a string. I wouldn't rely on this behavior. It depends on your environment's implementation of test(). (match fails because numbers don't have a `match` member). I'd reccomend explicitly converting your number to a string if you want to use it with a regex (`String(123)` for example).

Comment: The match can be used here, but if you look at performance, `test` performs 30% better when we just want to validate a string to match the regex and not extract substrings from it.

Comment: @pmrotule Yeah, but it should be mentioned before match description.

Comment: The most significant difference between test and match (and matchAll) is that match does things like to return a list of all matching sub-strings, while test only checks if there are any.  
Check the regex methods in https://javascript.info/regexp-methods

Comment: @Bronzdragon this answer claims that it doesn't work with `match`, even though `match` would be called the same way. Why would the same coercion not occur there?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because `match` is not a prototype function of `Number`, you would need to convert it to a string first.

Comment: The same coercion *can* happens if `.match()` were to be called with `.call()`: `String.prototype.match.call(12345, /^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/)`

Answer (score 63):

Use `/youregexp/.test(yourString)` if you only want to know whether your string matches the regexp.

Answer (score 26):

Here's an example that looks for certain HTML tags so it's clear that `/someregex/.test()` returns a boolean:

```js
if(/(span|h[0-6]|li|a)/i.test("h3")) alert('true');
```

**Remember** to indicate `^` for beginning of the string and `$` for the end, if you want to test the exact match of entire string.

Example:

```
/[a-z]+/.test('aaa111'); // true
/^[a-z]+$/.test('aaa111'); // false
```

Answer (score 24):

```js
let str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
let regexp = /[a-d]/gi;
console.log(str.match(regexp));
```

Answer (score 13):

```js
const regExpStr = "^([a-z0-9]{5,})$"
const result = new RegExp(regExpStr, 'g').test("Your string") // here I have used 'g' which means global search
console.log(result) // true if it matched, false if it doesn't
```

Answer (score 7):

try

```
 /^[a-z\d]{5,}$/.test(str)
```

```js
console.log( /^[a-z\d]{5,}$/.test("abc123") );

console.log( /^[a-z\d]{5,}$/.test("ab12") );
```

Comment: What new value does this code-only answer bring to the page?

Comment: currently it is shortest solution (due to regexp simplification)

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the execute method which returns null if no match exists otherwise it returns a helpful object.

```
let case1 = /^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.exec("abc1");
console.log(case1); //null

let case2 = /^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.exec("pass3434");
console.log(case2); // ['pass3434', 'pass3434', index:0, input:'pass3434', groups: undefined]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this, it works for me.

```
 <input type="text"  onchange="CheckValidAmount(this.value)" name="amount" required>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckValidAmount(amount) {          
       var a = /^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/;
       if(amount.match(a)){
           alert("matches");
       }else{
        alert("does not match"); 
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

please try this flower:

```
/^[a-z0-9\_\.\-]{2,20}\@[a-z0-9\_\-]{2,20}\.[a-z]{2,9}$/.test('abc@abc.abc');
```

> true

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want ^ and $ around the regex (I had such a usecase) you can do something like

```js
let reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g
let txt = "hello"
let matches = reg.exec(txt)[0] == txt
console.log(`It ${matches ? "does" : "doesn't"} match`)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Update/Add**

If the query string does not present in the URL then the below solution will work to add the param in the URL, if it already exists then it will update.

```
function updateUrlParameter(url, param, value) {
  var regex = new RegExp("(?<=[?|&])(" + param + "=)[^&]+", "i");
  if (regex.test(url)) {
    return url.replace(regex, param + "=" + value);
  } else {
    if (window.location.search) {
      return `${url}&${param}=${value}`;
    }else{
      return `${url}?${param}=${value}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `match()` seems to check whether part of a string matches a regex, not the whole thing. Does it solve the problem? Can I adapt it to solve the problem? How?

Yes, you can. `^` and `$` *are not needed* if you so choose.

The idea is simple: `.match()` [returns a "match" array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value). If the first element (i.e. the whole match, or `$0`) equals to the string, then we have a full match.

```js
function fullMatch(string, regex) {
  const match = string.match(regex);
  return match?.[0] === string;
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function fullMatch(string, regex) {
  const match = string.match(regex);
  console.log(match);
  return match?.[0] === string;
}

const string = 'f00bar';
const testcases = [
  /\d+c?ba/, // false
  /f\d+\w+/, // true
  /[0a-z]+/g // false
];

testcases.forEach(
  regex => console.log(fullMatch(string, regex))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this does not work with `g` regexes, as this flag causes `.match()` to always return a normal array if there is at least one match.

You can, however, use [`RegExp#exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead:

```js
function fullMatch(string, regex) {
  const match = regex.exec(regex);
  return match?.[0] === string;
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function fullMatch(string, regex) {
  const match = regex.exec(string);
  console.log(match);
  return match?.[0] === string;
}

const string = 'f00bar';
const testcases = [
  /\d+c?ba/, // false
  /f\d+\w+/, // true
  /[0a-z]+/g // true
];

testcases.forEach(
  regex => console.log(fullMatch(string, regex))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

One-liner:

```js
const fullMatch = (string, array) => regex.exec(string)?.[0] === string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `RegExp.prototype.test()` is probably correct, but has a couple caveats:

- It will tell you whether a string "matches" a regex -- i.e. if it "contains a matching sequence" -- not whether the string is an "exact match".
- If a regex is global `/g` it actually stores state, from the MDN:

> JavaScript RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or sticky flags set (e.g., /foo/g or /foo/y). They store a lastIndex from the previous match...
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

This means, for the first point, you need to use anchors, where `^` indicates the start of a string, and `$` indicates it's end. So a regex matching the full string "Cat" & nothing else would be: `/^Cat$/`

And secondly, you *cannot* reuse `regex.test(str)` with a global regex on the same string for this purpose, as it's meaning changes over time. E.g. (and note the failure, despite using different instances of string)

```
reg = /t/g;
console.log(reg.lastIndex); // 0 -- Never run
console.log(reg.test("Cat")); // true -- Matched "t"
console.log(reg.lastIndex); // 3 -- 3rd character was "t"
console.log(reg.test("Cat")); // false -- no more matches!
```