# Form validation with javascript not submitting

Tags: javascript, validation

I've been having trouble with validating an email input in a form.

Now I'm able to alert the user if they didn't input an email, or if the input is incorrect. However, if the input IS correct, it still alerts that the input is incorrect.

```
document.getElementById("frmContact").onsubmit = function() {

    if (document.getElementById("email").value=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.")
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("email").value !== "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"){
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: why don't you use HTML5 validation?

Comment: It looks like you're comparing the input to a regular expression, not using a regular expression to *match* the input.

Comment: It would be easier and quicker for us if you give us a jsFiddle that we could work with.

Comment: So are you expecting the value to match that string that looks a lot like a regex ?

Comment: Also, email `john@louvre.museum` is perfectly valid, but will fail your check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: check a string matches a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/javascript-check-a-string-matches-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the invalid email alert is this line of code:

```
else if (document.getElementById("email").value !== "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$")
```

This says if the content of the input tag with the id attribute of "email" does not equal the following string "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" then alert Please enter a valid email address.

What you want is to test that the input matches that regular expression like so:

```
var inputString = document.getElementById("email").value,
    patt = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$");

if (inputString === '') {
    alert("Please enter your email.")
    return false;
}
else if(!patt.test(inputString)) 
{//if the regex you specified matches its valid email(according to your regex) so negate and display error msg 
    alert("invalid e-mail");
    return false;
}
else
{
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the regular expression incorrectly; you don't want to compare the email string to the regex string directly; you need to use javascript's match() method to test your value against a regular expression. For example:

```
var regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
var matches = document.getElementById("email").value.match(regex);
if(!matches.length){
    alert("bad email");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It returns boolean value based on its validity

```
document.getElementById("frmContact").onsubmit = function() {

    if (document.getElementById("email").value=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.")
        return false;
    } else if (!validEmail(document.getElementById("email").value)){
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};


function validEmail(e) {
    var filter = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    return String(e).search(filter) != -1;
}
```