# RegEx to allow english and french alphabets

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a small javascript validation to allow english and french alphabets. This is how I have the regex...but its returning false. I was looking at this

[Check whether a string matches a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex)

```
var string = "évaÀ";
var re = new RegExp("/[^a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]/");
if (re.test(string)) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/e36jquLf/1/

Comment: It's probably the `[^a` part. get rid of the caret `^`.

Comment: Also the whole thing is wrong. It should be `/^[a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*$/`

Comment: @Louy -- I added the fiddle. I Updated the string with your expression but it still returns false

Comment: [Visualize it and see why it is not working](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%20%C3%A0%C3%A2%C3%A4%C3%A8%C3%A9%C3%AA%C3%AB%C3%AE%C3%AF%C3%B4%C5%93%C3%B9%C3%BB%C3%BC%C3%BF%C3%A7%C3%80%C3%82%C3%84%C3%88%C3%89%C3%8A%C3%8B%C3%8E%C3%8F%C3%94%C5%92%C3%99%C3%9B%C3%9C%C5%B8%C3%87%5D%2F)

Comment: Drop the `new Regex` part or the `/` at both ends.

Comment: also don't use spaces. `var re = /^[a-zA-Z\sàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*$/;`

Comment: @Louy-- that actually did work

Answer (score 2):

You want the `^` to be outside the brackets, and make sure you have any amount of these charecters inbetween the start `^` and the end `$` of the string:
(You also need to remove the `"..."`, and you don't realy need the `new RegEx`)

```js
var string = "évaÀ";
var re = /^[a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*$/
if (re.test(string)) {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}

// For the Demo-Input
function test(el) {
  if (/^[a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*$/.test(el.value)) {
    el.style.background = "green"
  } else {
    el.style.background = "red"
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" oninput="test(this)" placeholder="test any string here" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var string = "évaÀ"
if(string.match(/^[a-zA-Z àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]+$/)){
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know why you have marked the answer negative, according to me it at least doesn't fail to give the expected output.