# Use IF operator to diverge actions on alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric elements in a given array

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

I need help working on arrays that can contain both ALPHANUMERIC and NON-ALPHANUMERIC elements.

I need to perform an action for ALPHANUMERIC, and a different action for NON-ALPHANUMERIC.

I have been trying different ways to declare the statement If to diverge the two options, but I don't come up with the right formula.

The closest solution I can get is too dirty, I just tell the program the element has to be different from " " and diferent from "!" and different from "?". Not a clean solution. Could someone help? Maybe using a RegEx Expression?

```
  var myArray=["H","O","W"," ","A","R","E"," ","U","?"];
  var i=0;


  while(i<myArray.length){

  if(myArray[i]!=" " && myArray[i]!="!"&& myArray[i]!="?"&& myArray[i]!="."){
  //PERFORM ACTION 1 Example:
  return: "Hello";
  }


  else{
  //PERFORM ACTION 2 Example:
  return: "Goodbye";
  }

  i++;
  }
```

I have tried with the following Regex, and not succeded:

```
if(myArray[i]!=[A-Za-z0-9_])
```

and also:

```
if(myArray[i]!=/\W/g)
```

None of them work :( Help, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you iterating over array? If yes, add complete code, if not, you need to.

Comment: To check alphanumeric characters, use regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` with `test()`.

Comment: `ARRAY[i]` can not have all the values mentioned in the conditions. You should be using `||` instead..

Comment: Actually, `ARRAY[i]` can ***not*** be all those values. How about fixing the obvious syntax errors first, like the missing comma in the array

Comment: `if ( [" ", "!", "."].indexOf(myArray[i]) === -1 ) return "Hello";`

Comment: My code is able to sort out space, exclamation mark, question mark, and dot. Now I want to find a expression that sorts out anything that is not a letter. If it's a letter say Hello (example action), if it's something else (space, question mark, etc), say Goodbye.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a string matches a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
var myArray=["H","O","W"," ","A","R","E"," ","U","?"];
var i=0;
var alphaChecker = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");



while(i<myArray.length){

if(alphaChecker.test(myArray[i])){
//PERFORM ACTION 1 Example:
myArray[i]= "Hello";
}


else{
//PERFORM ACTION 2 Example:
myArray[i]= "Goodbye";
}

i++;
}

return myArray;
```

This works well.