# Regular expression validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking to validate an input text against the following pattern in JS/JQuery: `<some_string>:<some_string>`.

Examples:

- `A110:B120`
- `AB12C:B123`

I know this might be too naive, but appreciate any help here.

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted result ...

Comment: Based on what you say, you can only validate `:` and not `:`, which is `^[^:]+:[^:]+$`. Anything more specific and you will _miss_ matches you should get.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+:[A-Z0-9]+$
```

That will match your examples and any other that has at least 1 character in each side and only has upper case letters and numbers.

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603043/3645944) in order to know how to test a regex against a string.

Comment: Prefer `[A-Z0-9]+` to `[A-Z0-9]{1,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"A110:B120 AB12C:B123".match(/(\w+:\w+)/);

MATCH 
1.  `A110:B120`
2.  `AB12C:B123`
```

or

```
"A110:B120".match(/(\w+)+:+(\w+)/);

MATCH 
1.  A110
2.  B120
```