# JS | RegEx Match URLs & return value based on match

Tags: javascript, regex, match, indexof

I'm trying to search for a specific string within URL and if the value is found, I want the script to return a page type.

I was using a simple indexOf, but it doesn't allow for RegEx & I can't seem to make this script work with using match.

I'm a newbie & any help is appreciated! :)

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf("/czech-job-server/") > -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf("/prague/czech/") > -1)) {
   return("Detail");
}

else if (window.location.href.indexOf("jobs") > -1) {
   return("Category");
}

else {
   return("Page Not Defined");
}
```

Comment: could you put an example string input and output for us?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to this - if you tried to use `.match()`, how did you use it and what happened, can you show that code? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex for examples

Comment: Yes, I've tried match() instead indexOf -> 

e.g. window.location.href.match(job-server/g) > -1

Sadly I'm triggering the script through Google Tag Manager, so I don't have any other code to show you. It's just returning "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i didn't see a pattern to use regex, so just put the word in an regex and call match. 
[Match method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of matches in current string:

```
var hrefString = window.location.href;

if ((hrefString.match(/czech-job-server/g).length > 0) || (hrefString.match(/prague\/czech/g).length > 0)) {

   return("Detail");
}

else if (hrefString.match(/jobs/g).length > -1) {
   return("Category");
}

else {
   return("Page Not Defined");
}
```

Comment: Phew, it's finally working. I've just made a few changes to your code. Thank you :-).

----

function () {
  
if ((window.location.href.match(/czech-job-server/g).length > 0) || (hrefString.match(/prague\/czech/g).length > 0)) {
   return("Detail");
}

else if (window.location.href.match(/jobs/g).length > 0) {
   return("Category");
}

else {
   return("Page Not Defined");
}

}