# alpha numeric validation is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

For a Angular 2 application, I wrote a custom validator TypeScript class like below,

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class AlphaNumericValidator {
    static invalidAlphaNumeric(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
        if (control.value.length && !control.value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
            return { invalidAlphaNumeric: true };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am applying this validator for a Model Driven Form,

```
'name': [this.exercise.name, [Validators.required, AlphaNumericValidator.invalidAlphaNumeric]],
```

And Here is the HTML,

```
<label *ngIf="exerciseForm.controls.name.hasError('invalidAlphaNumeric') && (exerciseForm.controls.name.touched || submitted)" class="alert alert-danger validation-message">Name must be alphanumeric</label>
```

I notice that whenever I am typing a character in input, the above TypeScript class code called, but every time it's return Null.

Is there any issue on typeScript class?

Thanks!

Comment: Can only be because `control.value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)` always matches

Comment: then what would be the correct regex for alpha numeric

Comment: What do you get when you add `console.log(control.value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i));` before th `if(...)`?

Comment: ["b", index: 0, input: "b"]              for a character 'b'

Comment: You could try `/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(control.value)` instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex

Comment: i tried this, but now even for valid alphanumeric values, error message always appreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(control.value)
```

to get a boolean result

Comment: i tried this, but now even for valid alphanumeric values, error message always appreas

Comment: Can't reproduce. This works fine in the browser console like `!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test('abc')` (`false`) or `!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test('ab.)` (`true`)

Comment: will it be possible that one character should be number and one character should be non-number?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What exactly do you want to allow/disallow?

Comment: for input "abc" should be true, for "234" also true, but for "7Alph" should false. the input content must contain at lease a character and a number

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what about strictly Alpha (uppercase and or lowercase) or Strictly numeric characters? Something like `/(^[a-z]+$)|(^[A-Z]+$)/i` Not sure?