# Regex inside `if` check

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex inside `if`. Strange, but it doesn't work. How it may be fixed?

It works:

```
var lang = 'lang-js';
if (lang == 'lang-js') {
  alert('ok');
}
```

It works too (just for testing purposes):

```
var lang = 'lang-js';
if (lang == 'lang-' + 'js') {
  alert('ok');
}
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
var lang = 'lang-js';
if (lang == 'lang-' + /[a-z]/) {
  alert('not ok');
}
```

Comment: Type `'lang-' + /[a-z]/` in the browser console and see what happens. You're not doing a regular expression test, you are concatenating a regex with a string, which produces a string, and then comparing that with another string. This has nothing to do with jQuery so I've removed that tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use something like this

```
if (/^lang-[a-z]/.test(lang)) {
```

you might have to adjust the regex as this just looks for one char.

Answer (score 0):

its because `typeof /[a-z]/ == 'object'` and where `''+/[a-z]/` working `toString` and your result will be string `lang-/[a-z]/`