# JS: How to get the site name?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Example urls:

- `let str = 'https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico'`
- `let str1 = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico'`
- `let str2 = 'https://books.google.com.ua/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico'`

How can I get only the site name from such urls? Only the word - google.

Comment: what do you mean by site name? lets say for str2 what are you expecting?

Comment: Sarath Kumar, this answer is not suitable. There does not account for the subdomain and second level domain.

Comment: so, what you are expecting for str2?

Comment: samnu pel, yes site name

Comment: Koushik Chatterjee, str - google, str1 - google, str2 - google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works reasonably well:

`https?.*?(\w{4,})(?=(?:\.\w{2,3})+\/)`

The name is in group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZNaNes/1). It's likely better to use a whitelist of TLDs.

Comment: Can you make js function?

Comment: Here is an example how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/8315377

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oePLPE      Almost what I need. How to add www?

Comment: and http, please

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will return the group `name` with what you want:

```
[.+:\/\/]?[^.]*\.?(?<name>[^.]+).+
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndQ2oz/3)

It will work in cases of urls like `https://google.com.br`, for example.Let me know if you think this way is sufficient.

**EDIT:**

It is very difficult to treat cases like I pointed:

- books.google.com
- books.londrina.br

In the first case, the correct return would be `google`, but in the second case the desirable result is `books`.

Comment: this does not detract from the subdomain, if I understand correctly. Can make of this js function?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex.