# JavaScript Regular Expression to Replace Escape Special Characters from String

Tags: javascript, json

I have an issue with JavaScript Regular Expression to Replace Escape Special Characters from String like for example 1)

```
var = test{test}/uk/london=?paris{},clients,vague>;
```

and I want to extract the result only  in just this format = `/uk/london`
so I only want `/uk/london` from the line above how do I code this in javascript?

Comment: `var = test{test}/uk/london=?paris{},clients,vague>` is invalid

Comment: Do you want to explicitly extract only `/uk/london` or are you looking for the pattern that consists of a slash followed by a word then another slash followed by another word?

Comment: Do you always want everything from the first "/" to the first "=" ?

Comment: `let str = 'test{test}/uk/london=?paris{},clients,vague>'; str.match(/\/(.*)=/)[1]`

Comment: yes explicitly extract like from /uk/london to just before = sign

Comment: @smac89  yes explicitly extract like from /uk/london to just before = sign

Comment: api/v1/Projectlook/GetAllAnswers?clientCode={clientCode}&username={username}&password={password}&httpsessionid={httpsessionid}  .....       From this line I Only want Projectlook/GetAllAnswers      @smac89

Comment: api/v1/Projectlook/GetAllAnswers?clientCode={clientCode}&username={username}&password={password}&httpsessionid={httpsessionid}  .....       From this line I Only want Projectlook/GetAllAnswers      @AndrewMorton

Comment: api/v1/Projectlook/GetAllAnswers?clientCode={clientCode}&username={username}&password={password}&httpsessionid={httpsessionid}  .....       From this line I Only want Projectlook/GetAllAnswers    @junvar

Comment: So it seems you want the pattern, not the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "test{test}/uk/london=?paris{},clients,vague>";
var re = /(\/.*)=/;
var t = re.exec(s)[1];
console.log(t);
```

outputs to the console:

> /uk/london

The part in parentheses is captured in a group.
That group starts with a "/" (which has to be escaped by the "\") and the rest of it can be any character "." any number of times "*".
The ".*" is stopped by the requirement to match "=".

`exec` executes the regex, and `[1]` gets the first group.

Comment: Hi I'm, getting an error  called cannot read property '1' of null any help on this as its pointing to var t= this line ?  @AndrewMorton             
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
 var length = jsonData.length;
  for(var i=0;i<length;  i++)
   {


          var jesb =[];
          var re= /(\/.*)=/;
          var t = re.exec(jesb)[1];
         jesb[i] =jsonData[i].RelativePath;
      
      
          console.log(jesb[i]);
          

   }

Comment: @jezza That means that there was not a match. You can [Check whether a string matches a regex in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603043/1115360) to see if there will be a `[1]` item.