# Regular expression for entering values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sample format for which I want the regular expression in JavaScript. The format is as below.

```
I-KA-BGLK-ENB-V001
```

I am unable to try as I don't know much about regular expressions. How can I write a suitable one?

Even if I get the regex it will do, the JavaScript part I can handle.

Comment: what do you want to do with the regex? validate string to be of this format?

Comment: Your question is very vague. How do we infer the format from that sample? You should give examples and tell the format explicitly. Read about regular expressions here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @InusSaha: yes, I want to validate it. so user cant enter the invalid string

Comment: *Unable to try as I dont know much about the Regex* is incredibly lazy. Go through a basic tutorial, then come back with a more specific question. https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-regular-expressions-for-beginners-bb6107015d91

Comment: "Unable" to even *try*?! :/ I mean, ok, not knowing something is fine, not even trying... I don't get it. Maybe it's a good time to learn about regex-they're pretty important. And handy.

Answer (score 1):

The valid regular expression for this is:

```
^\w-\w{2}-\w{4}-\w{3}-\w{4}$
^\w-\w{2}-\w{4}-\w{3}-\w\d{3}$
```

**Explanation**

[image: exp1]

[image: expl]

**Code**

I don't want to spoon-feed you, but the next step is to [Check whether a string matches a regex in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6603015).

Comment: @BNN Welcome... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var str = 'I-KA-BGLK-ENB-V001';

var re = /^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]\d{3}$/;

re.test(str);// true
```

[A-Z] - means any uppercase letter

\d - means any digit 0-9

\d{3} - means 3 digits

[A-Z]{2} - means 2 uppercace letters

You can change if you need digits in some places.

If you dont care about lowercase or uppercase replace [A-Z] with \w

https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex - lessons
Or you google "learn regex easy"

Answer (score 0):

Well to match strings in the `I-KA-BGLK-ENB-V001` format you can use this regex:

```
^[A-Z]\-[A-Z]{2}\-[A-Z]{4}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\w{4}$
```

You can test it [in **Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/KdU93P/2), where you can see an example of matching strings and check the meaning and the specifications for each part of it.