# Match a text box prompt input to a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, cognos

I have this code, where I want to check two textbox prompts in Cognos and match it to a regular expression. This works if I want to check for only numbers and use isNaN() in the second if statement. But it doesn't work when I want to match it to a regularexpression. And I don't know why that is.

```
oCR = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
    var f1 = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('prompt1');
    var f2 = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('prompt2');
    var prompts = [f1,f2];

    for (var i=0;i < prompts.length;i++) {
            prompts[i].setValidator(validate);
    }

function validate(values) {
    var result = false;
    var pattern = /[A-Z]{4}\d{2}/;
    if (values.length > 0) {
        if (values[0].use == pattern) {
            result = true;
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a string matches a regex in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (values[0].use.match(pattern))
```