# In AppEngine logs viewer can I filter by labels that do not match a pattern

Tags: google-app-engine

AppEngine logs viewer has the ability to filter by labels.  For example if I want to find all logs where the url starts with /static, I can put the filter with Labels option selected as

```
path:/static.*
```

However, what should I put such that the filter **shows logs that do NOT match** this pattern?  Attempting examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence) crashed the log viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax should have been

```
path:/(?!static).*
```

However, this does not work either.

In the meantime, assuming you have no other urls starting with `s`, you could do

```
path:/[^s].*
```

ps: next time you find a crash or a bug, could you please file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.

**EDIT:**

In the general case the regex would be

```
path:/([^s]|s[^t]|st[^a]|sta[^t]|stat[^i]|stati[^c]).*
```

Comment: The latter is exactly what I am doing now.  But I have two URIs starting with "s".

Comment: Depending on the other url, you could do something like: path:/([^s]|s[^t]).*   (this assumes the second character of the other url is not a t). If, for example, the first differing character is the 4th one, you could use  path:/([^s]|sta[^i]).*

Comment: In the general case the regex would be path:/([^s]|s[^t]|st[^a]|sta[^t]|stat[^i]|stati[^c]).*

Comment: Not the most elegant of solutions, but it works.  
In the absence of another option, can you please add this to your answer so that I may upvote it for posterity?

Comment: I know, but at least it solves the problem. I already filed an internal ticket for this.