# maven-war-plugin: exclude all directories but one

Tags: java, maven, build-process

I have a directory structure as:

[image: screenshot]

```
src
|__ main
    |__ java
    |__ resources
    |__ webapp
        |__ css_blue
        |__ css_green
        |__ css_red
        |__ WEB-INF
```

where there are three seperate directories of css (as `css_red`, `css_green`, `css_blue`). Here, I want to include only one of them based on the `-D` switch as:

```
mvn clean install -Dcss=green
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.faisal.dwr</groupId>
  <artifactId>chatbox</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring - MVC -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Web Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security Config -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DWR -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
      <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <packagingIncludes>css_${css}</packagingIncludes>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But in this case files and directories under `WEB-INF` not present in the final `.war` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the [`packagingIncludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingIncludes) attribute of the `maven-war-plugin` will include everything under `src/main/webapp`. When you override it to specify

```xml
<packagingIncludes>css_${css}/**</packagingIncludes>
```

then the plugin will only include that folder (and everything under it) and not `WEB-INF` anymore. A simple solution is to re-include `WEB-INF`:

```xml
<packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/**,css_${css}/**</packagingIncludes>
```

With such a configuration, everything under `WEB-INF` and everything under `css_${css}` will be included in the war.

---

Another solution that does not require re-adding folders would be to use [`<packagingExcludes>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes) instead. This way, all files under `src/main/webapp` will be included, except those that we specify here. In this case, we can use a regular expression that says: exclude everything that starts with `css` [and is not `css_${css}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899448/1743880).

```xml
<packagingExcludes>%regex[css_(?!${css}/).*]</packagingExcludes>
```

Comment: Now this works like a charm. Thanks for the help! Could you explain the thing works in `%regex[]`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal `?!` is called "negative look-ahead". I linked to a question about this construct. It matches Strings that do not start with another string.

Comment: one issue I am facing after adding this expression while updating dependencies from eclipse - `An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Illegal repetition near index 7 css_(?!${css}/).*` which is pointing an arraow(`^`) around `(?`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Hmm, this sounds like an issue of m2e. Try to update it to the latest version, along with Eclipse.