# In PyParsing, how to specify one or more lines which do not start with a certain string?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse some fields from a multi-line file, of which I'm only interested in some lines, while others I would like to skip. Here is an example of something similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
from pyparsing import *

string = "field1: 5\nfoo\nbar\nfield2: 42"

value1 = Word(nums)("value1")
value2 = Word(nums)("value2")
not_field2 = Regex(r"^(?!field2:).*$")

expression = "field1:" + value1 + LineEnd() + OneOrMore(not_field2)+ "field2:" + value2 + LineEnd()

tokens = expression.parseString(string)

print tokens["value1"]
print tokens["value2"]
```

where the `Regex` for a line not starting with `field2:` is adapted from [Regular expression for a string that does not start with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence). However, running this example script gives a

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected Re:('^(?!field2:).*$') (at char 10), (line:2, col:1)
```

I would like the `value2` to end up as `42`, regardless of the number of lines (`foo\n` and `bar\n` in this case). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '^' and '$' characters in your Regex aren't interpreted on a line-by-line basis by pyparsing, but in the context of the whole string being parsed. So '^' will match *only* at the very beginning of the string and '$' *only* at the very end.

Instead you can do:

```
not_field2 = LineStart() + Regex(r"(?!field2:).*")
```