# How can I validate a github branch name as a string parameter in jenkins parametrized job?

Tags: regex, validation, github, jenkins, branch

[image]

How can I do some github branch name validation in jenkins?

branch should contain only 26 alphanumeric characters and hyphens
branch should **NOT** begin with ***www***, ***api*** or ***admin***

One regex for this could be:

```
^(?!www)(?!admin)(?!api)[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,26}$
```

My problem is that I want to do this validation when the job is run.

Where should i put such regex validation for the branch name in jenkins?

PS: in the attached image, that branch for instance is an illegal branch name ... it breaks the validation rule because it starts with www.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found an answer how to validate the branch name:

I can use a jenkins plugin : Validate String Parameter

See image attached [image]

Note the

> This message is displayed to the user if they enter a value that does not match the configured regular expression.

I basically want the opposite ... 
**I want the message to show WHEN the branch matches the regex:**

```
^(www|api|admin)\w{1,26}$
```

Brain is frozen ... How do I do this?

Comment: please edit your posting instead of putting additional questions inside an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see "[Regular expression for a string that does not start with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899448/6309)" and see if the regexp engine used within Jenkins (the java one I suppose) allows for a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
^(?!www|?!api|?!admin)\w{1,26}$
# or
^(?!(www|api|admin))\w{1,26}$
```