# How to remove a specific pattern from re.findall() results

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a re.findall() searching for a pattern in python, but it returns some undesired results and I want to know how to exclude them. The text is below, I want to get the names, and my statement (`re.findall(r'([A-Z]{4,} \w. \w*|[A-Z]{4,} \w*)', text)`) is returning this:

```
 'ERIN E. SCHNEIDER',
 'MONIQUE C. WINKLER',
 'JASON M. HABERMEYER',
 'MARC D. KATZ',
 'JESSICA W. CHAN',
 'RAHUL KOLHATKAR',
 'TSPU or taken',
 'TSPU or the',
 'TSPU only',
 'TSPU was',
 'TSPU and']
```

I want to get rid of the "TSPU" pattern items. Does anyone know how to do it?

> JINA L. CHOI (NY Bar No. 2699718)
>
> ERIN E. SCHNEIDER (Cal. Bar No. 216114) schneidere@sec.gov
>
> MONIQUE C. WINKLER (Cal. Bar No. 213031) winklerm@sec.gov
>
> JASON M. HABERMEYER (Cal. Bar No. 226607) habermeyerj@sec.gov
>
> MARC D. KATZ (Cal. Bar No. 189534) katzma@sec.gov
>
> JESSICA W. CHAN (Cal. Bar No. 247669) chanjes@sec.gov
>
> RAHUL KOLHATKAR (Cal. Bar No. 261781) kolhatkarr@sec.gov
>
> 1. The Investor Solicitation Process Generally Included a Face-to-Face Meeting, a Technology Demonstration, and a Binder of Materials [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?!TSPU\b)[A-Z]{4,}(?:(?:\s+\w\.)?\s+\w+)?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJAf2F/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (else, the regex may "catch" a part of a word that contains `TSPU`)
- `(?!TSPU\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `TSPU` string followed with a non-word char or end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `[A-Z]{4,}` - four or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?:(?:\s+\w\.)?\s+\w+)?` - an optional occurrence  of:

  - `(?:\s+\w\.)?` - an optional occurrence of one or more whitespaces, a word char and a literal `.` char
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars.

In Python, you can use

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?!TSPU\b)[A-Z]{4,}(?:(?:\s+\w\.)?\s+\w+)?', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple `.filter`-ing, if your array was `results`,

```py
removed_TSPU_results = list(filter(lambda: not result.startswith("TSPU"), results))
```

Comment: The idea was to do it in the regex statement

Comment: @Gabriel use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence