# How to match "cc dd" that doesn't start with "aa"

Tags: python, regex

I want to match `cc dd` that doesn't start with `aa`

```
import re

s = 'bb cc dd ee\naa : bb cc dd ee\n11 cc dd ee'
pp = re.compile(r'(?P<n1>ee)|(?P<n2>^(?!aa\b).*\bcc dd\b)', re.MULTILINE)

def _rep(x):
    print(x.groupdict())
    return [f'<{k}>' for k, v in x.groupdict().items() if v is not None][0]

rr = pp.sub(_rep, s)
print(rr)
```

Result: Current

```
# print(x.groupdict())
    {'n1': None, 'n2': 'bb cc dd'}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}
    {'n1': None, 'n2': '11 cc dd'}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}

# print(rr)
    <n2> <n1>
    aa : bb cc dd <n1>
    <n2> <n1>
```

Result: I want ..

```
# print(x.groupdict())
    {'n1': None, 'n2': 'cc dd'}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}
    {'n1': None, 'n2': 'cc dd'}
    {'n1': 'ee', 'n2': None}

# print(rr)
    bb <n2> <n1>
    aa : bb cc dd <n1>
    11 <n2> <n1>
```

Comment: It is `^(?!aa).*cc dd`. What do you  intend to do with the match? Replace? Extract?

Comment: With word boundaries it should be: `^(?!aa\b).*\bcc dd\b`

Comment: Like `re.sub(r'^(?!aa\b)(.*)\bcc dd\b', 'r\1New Text', text)` /  `re.sub(r'^(?!aa\b)(.*?)\bcc dd\b', 'r\1New Text', text)`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899422/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-does-not-start-with-a-sequence

Comment: I added my code.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `re`, it won't be possible to achieve what you need because you expect multiple occurrences per string that will be replaced later, and you need a variable-width lookbehind pattern support (not available in `re`).

You need to install the PyPi `regex` module by launching `pip install regex` in your terminal/console and then use

```py
import regex

s = 'bb cc dd ee\naa : bb cc dd ee\n11 cc dd ee'
pp = regex.compile(r'(?P<n1>ee)|(?<!^aa\b.*)\b(?P<n2>cc dd)\b', regex.MULTILINE)

def _rep(x):
    #print(x.groupdict())
    return [f'<{k}>' for k, v in x.groupdict().items() if v is not None][0]

rr = pp.sub(_rep, s)
print(rr)
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY/BTsMwDIbveQojDklQVVG4TaU7cZg0Jg5wWgdqWndEo4nlpKgIePbSFTRpvv3@/OmX6TO@eXc7jrYjzxEY9zgIEeAOpDFQ19A0gFi6qoIFnG2y7BSkIJqMWU5r35F9R8VSLR9zlxWI@lst84uXqipNeqVLM4ObYtanKJN/9eF5/bRarzb3WogGW3hlJDXohYBpLomti2pI9@x7amwdldYzYYw9O9i2Mv86/BQSWs9wSOADrIOz@9RG7ILSYNsjDeB8hI13uNte74Rgnr4gSkNv1LE7gaDFXy2zHsdf).

Here, `(?<!^aa\b.*)\b(?P<n2>cc dd)\b` matches a whole word `cc dd` capturing it into `n2` group that is not immediately preceded with `aa` whole word at the beginning of the current line (`regex.MULTILINE` with `^` make this anchor match any line start position and `.*` makes sure the check is performed even if `cc dd` is not immediately preceded with `aa`.